# How to align the text and icon on a tag inside a paragraph tag?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to align the text and icon on a tag inside a paragraph tag.

I've shared the HTML code I'm using,

```
            <div class="application-intro">
             <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-pen"></i><span>Sample text 1</span></a></p>
             <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-arrow-up"></i><span>Sample text 2</span></a></p>
             <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-magnifying-glass"></i><span>Sample text 3</span></a></p>
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because icon don't have the same width by default

```css
.application-intro p i {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="application-intro">
  <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-pen"></i><span>Sample text 1</span></a></p>
  <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-arrow-up"></i><span>Sample text 2</span></a></p>
  <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-magnifying-glass"></i><span>Sample text 3</span></a></p>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

A way to solve that is to put same width to all icon

```css
.application-intro p i {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="application-intro">
  <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-pen"></i><span>Sample text 1</span></a></p>
  <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-arrow-up"></i><span>Sample text 2</span></a></p>
  <p><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fas fa-magnifying-glass"></i><span>Sample text 3</span></a></p>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```